# How to deploy a Flask application on pythonanywhere with a folder as a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, deployment, pythonanywhere

Currently I am trying to a deploy my first FLASK application on PythonAnywhere.

Im not sure if this is the correct terminology but I have a folder as a module and there for I can't seem to find the correct way to deploy my application. I am not even sure where to start in resolving this issue. Any advice?

[File and Folder Layout Snipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHCYo.jpg)

my **init**.py code is:

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='secret',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'LAMA.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # database
    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    # authentication blueprint
    from . import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)


    # blog blueprint - the main index
    # from . import blog
    # app.register_blueprint(blog.bp)
    # app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

    # book blueprint 
    from . import book
    app.register_blueprint(book.bp)
    app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

    return app
```

I have also followed the python debugging page where I have done the following:

```
>>> import LAMA
>>> print(LAMA)
<module 'LAMA' from '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA/__init__.py'>
```

So at this stage in my WSGI configuration file I have:

```
import sys

path = '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA/__init__.py'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from LAMA import app as application
```

I have also tried many other combinations such as

```
path = '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA/'
from init import app as application

path = '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/'
from init import app as application

path = '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/'
from LAMA import app as application
```

my source code path is : /home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA , although I have also tried different combinations such as /home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/

**ERROR DETAIL:**

```
2018-12-08 10:05:32,028: Error running WSGI application
2018-12-08 10:05:32,030: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LAMA'
2018-12-08 10:05:32,030:   File "/var/www/ivanv257_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 83, in <module>
2018-12-08 10:05:32,030:     from LAMA import app as application  # noqa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem I changed the following (with some assistance) from lama import create_app:

```
import sys

path = '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from lama import create_app

application = create_app()
```

I also had to remove the from . to just imports

```
    import db
    db.init_app(app)

    # authentication blueprint
    import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. To deploy your app, navigate to the webapps page on your user dashboard. If you have not done so already, click the "Add new a webapp" button and enter the desired name of the app. Then, on the same webapp page on the dashboard, scroll down to the "Code" section of the page. Click on the "source code" `a href` and add the absolute path (full path) to the `lama_main` directory storing your `init.py` file.

Next, click on "WSGI configuration file" link. In the WSGI configuration file for your app, set the correct path to the parent directory and import `app` from the `init.py` file:

```
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/your_user_name/lama_main'
if project_home not in sys.path:
  sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work

from init import app as application #note that the module being imported from must be the file with "app" defined.
```

Then, save the WSGI file and return to the webapp panel on your dashboard. Click the "Reload {your site name}" button. Now, you should be able to visit the site by clicking on the main link at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks but Still no luck, still receiving an error: 



`2018-12-08 10:05:32,028: Error running WSGI application
2018-12-08 10:05:32,030: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LAMA'
2018-12-08 10:05:32,030:   File "/var/www/ivanv257_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 83, in <module>
2018-12-08 10:05:32,030:     from LAMA import app as application  # noqa`

Comment: Have you checked out [the PythonAnywhere help page on debugging import errors](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError)?  It explains how importing stuff works in Python, with specific reference to tracking down this kind of issue.

Comment: @Ivan You have to import from the file that defines the object `app`. It seems from your filestructure that `LAMA` is the full parent directory. Try changing `project_home` to the path pointing to `LAMA`.

Comment: Still can't seem to resolve this, unsure what I am doing wrong. 

I have tried multiple path combinations and import combinations still no solution. 

Currently I have:

`import sys

path = '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA/__init__.py'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from LAMA import app as application~ 


my source code directory is: /home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA
working directory: /home/ivanv257/

using the debugging guide on python anywhere I got
>>>print(LAMA) <module 'LAMA' from '/home/ivanv257/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA/__init__.py'>

Comment: The main problem with `from init import app as application` seems that the editor says `init.app as application imported but unused` .

Comment: @Ivan Your path should only point to the parent directory of `init.py` which, according to you file structure, should be `/user/{your_user_name}/something/something/LAMA_MAIN/LAMA`